# High-viscosity gel/polymer to suspend conductive material while it is being printed

Tags: print-material

I currently doing research on 3d printing on circuit boards. The technique we are using is to put a conductive material, I.e ceramics/metal in a gel/polymer, to print the suspension and then when is complete to sinter away the gel/polymer. The problem I am having is the suspension needs to be thixotropic. Furthermore it must have a high viscosity i.e 500 cpa under low shear and to quickly drop to low viscosity as the shear increases

So far the closest thing I have been able to find is in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0955221909003860) but if you look at the graphs none of them have a high enough viscosity and more importantly the drop to low viscosity under increasing shear is too shallow.

I have tried to use models like the ones in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377025714001463#s0055) but I am finding it quite difficult.

Does anyone have any suggestions to find more materials like the one I require? Thanks

Comment: Would something like [this conductive paste](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4IGQ5JMP6g) work?

Answer (score 2):

The material you are describing sounds very similar to the material used for [Metal Injection Molding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_injection_molding) except that you want to print the material rather than molding it.

A company called MarkForged is making a printer called the [Metal X](http://www.desktop3dprinter.com/3d-printers/markforged-metal-x.html) that uses this technique of [printing & sintering to produce solid metal parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7IsFQLjRNU&t=1s).  Here is a [article describing more details about the printer](http://www.additivemanufacturing.media/articles/markforged-metal-printer-sintering-can-wait).

It sounds really cool.

**If you investigate papers around those processes you may find what you are looking for since they are so related to what you are trying to do.**